# Trying to convert Ruby custom array accessor to C++ subscript operator override

Tags: c++, ruby

I'm learning how to generate mazes with the book "Mazes for Programmers: Code Your Own Twisty Little Passages". The examples are all in Ruby. I am currently learning advanced C++ and I want to convert this code.

```
def [](row, column)
  return nil unless row.between?(0, @rows - 1)
  return nil unless column.between?(0, @grid[row].count - 1)
@grid[row][column] end

#Buck, Jamis. Mazes for Programmers: Code Your Own Twisty Little Passages
#(p. 21). Pragmatic Bookshelf. Kindle Edition.
```

The code above returns a Cell object from the grid at the given row and column, if such Cell exists. I have looked into overriding the [] operator in C++ but the Ruby implementation uses a 2d array. I'm totally lost on how to implement this to check against both rows and columns.

---

Here is the header for the Grid Class:

```
#include "Cell.h"

class Grid
{
private:
    int rows;
    int columns;
    vector<vector<Cell>> grid;
public:
    Grid(int, int);
    ~Grid();
    void prepareGrid();
    void configureCells();
    Cell &operator[] (int,int);
};
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Cell & Grid::operator[](int row, int column)
{
    if (row >= rows) {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (column >= columns) {
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        return grid[row][column];
    }
}
```

---

- Edit for clarification

: The C++ operator[] does not allow for more than one parameter, so I cannot check against both rows and columns with a single override of the accessor

I also realize that returning NULL is not valid in this situation and need to figure out how to work around that.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm totally lost on how to implement this to check against both rows and columns.

Use `and` or `&&` like this:

```
if (row < rows && column < columns)
{
    // success
}
else
{
    // fail
}
```

For indicating failure you could change the function signature to return a `Cell*` which would allow you to return a `nullptr` (don't use `NULL`) or you could throw an exception.

Comment: I should have added that the C++ operator[] does not allow for more than one parameter, so I cannot pass both rows and columns to the overloaded function. I will update my original question to reflect this, thanks

Comment: Do you need to use operator[]? Otherwise you could just make it regular function and call it `at` or `get` or whatever. If you do need it then I guess you have to return a proxy object.